# Alpha image stacked on opaque texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency

Drawing a blank here. I'm trying to recreate Jack Sparrow's famous bandana; a red base colour with a blue floral pattern. I've started off with a red, diffuse base on my bandana mesh and I've acquired a decent image of a vector floral pattern with an alpha background.

My problem is: how do I then add this floral pattern on the surface of my red bandana? Can I not stack image textures in the same material?
The floral pattern is a png image, and its alpha channel is apparent when I use the alpha textured material method. However, I don't want my bandana to be transparent.

How do I add the floral pattern to the opaque base material while retaining the image's transparency?

Comment: "Jack Sparrow's famous bandana" Not everybody knows what that is. Please add a reference image.

Comment: Not sure to completely understand but maybe you have to do this: create a Mix Shader and plug it into your Material Output. Plug a Diffuse Shader into the first shader of this Mix Shader, for the background color. Plug another Diffuse Shader into the second shader of the Mix Shader. Plug an Image Texture into this second Diffuse and open the floral pattern. Plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture into the Factor of the Mix Shader. It should put the floral texture above your background. And of course the mesh of your bandana is supposed to be unwrapped but I guess it's already done.